# Comparing Sample Mean and a Random Variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, means

Let $X_{(i)} = ( i = 1,2, \ldots, n+1)$ be a random sample of size $n+1$ that is produced from a normal population. Let $M$ be the sample mean of the **first $n$ random variables** in this random sample.

Find the probability that $$P(X_{(n+1)} - M < 0.5)$$

Variance $= 1$ and Sample Size $n = 40$.

I have been stuck in this question for hours since I cannot find a formula to compute $X_{(n+1)}$.  I tried computing the sample mean including $(n+1)$ and then figure out something between two sample means but I went nowhere.

Am I interpreting this question wrong, isn't $X_{(n+1)}$ just a data value or does that notation mean its the sample mean of $n+1$ values? I cannot see how this problem could be solved if $X_{(n+1)}$ is a value ....

Answer (score 2):

The random variables $X_{n+1}$ and $M$ have the same mean. Let $Y=X_{+1}-M$. Then $Y$ has mean $0$.

The random variable $Y$ is a linear combination of independent normals, so it is normal.

Note that $X_{n+1}$ has variance $1$ and $M$ has variance $\frac{1}{40}$. Thus $Y$ has variance $1+(-1)^2\frac{1}{40}=\frac{41}{40}$.

Now that we know the mean and the variance of  the normally distributed random variable  $Y$, we can find $\Pr(Y\lt 0.5)$ in the usual way.

Comment: Thank you! I just have one question. How can X(n+1) and M have the same mean if M is equal to the sample mean? By that do you mean that they have the same population mean? Or are you talking about the expected values of X(n+1) and M ?

Comment: You are welcome. Mean, expected value, expectation are synonyms. If the $X_i$ have mean $\mu$, then since $M=\frac{1}{n}(X_1+\cdots+X_n)$, $M$ has mean $\mu$.

Comment: Thanks again:) just to be sure on this line:                    Note that X(n+1) has variance 1/ 40 and X (n+1) has variance 1 you meant the second X(n+1) as M right? :)

Comment: Thanks for spotting it, yes, it is $M$, corrected. It is supposed to be $X_{n+1}$ has variance $1$ and $M$ has variance $\frac{1}{40}$. That's what I used on the next line.